# Why is VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT an invalid choice for multisampling in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Hello people of StackOverflow,

I am currently working on a games engine using the Vulkan graphics API, in the past I was just setting anti-aliasing to the max it could be.  However today I was trying to turn it off (to improve performance on weaker systems).  To do this I tried to set the MSAA samples on my engine to VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT however this produced the validation error:

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-VkSubpassDescription-pResolveAttachments-00848 ] Object 0: handle = 0x55aaa6e32828, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0xfad6c3cb | ValidateCreateRenderPass():  Subpass 0 requests multisample resolve from attachment 0 which has VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT. The Vulkan spec states: If pResolveAttachments is not NULL, for each resolve attachment that is not VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED, the corresponding color attachment must not have a sample count of VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSubpassDescription-pResolveAttachments-00848)
```

I can work around this problem relatively easily so it isn't really an issue for me, however I was wondering why exactly this limit is put into place.  If I want to set the MSAA samples to 1 why can't I?

Thanks,
sckzor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample count of 1 means "not a multisampled image". And if you're doing multisample resolve, resolving from a non-multisampled image doesn't make sense. Which is also why you can't use such images for any other things that expect a multisampled image (you can't use an MS-style sampler or texture function on them).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I guess that what you said make sense, I was just wondering if there was any sort of deeper meaning behind that decision in the spec.  That does raise the question however, is there an easier way to disable MSAA without getting rid all of the resolving and forcing it to resolve straight to the screen?

Comment: @sckzor: The sample count is baked into the render pass (and therefore is baked into any pipelines used in that render pass). Therefore, to change the sample count, you must rebuild the render pass. So just check the sample count and see if it has 1 sample; if it does, don't resolve to it.